# Python driving me crazy with circular import

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, circular-dependency

From helpers.py:

```
import ...

from datasets import my_datasets

class Printable():
    def __str__(self):
        return 'foobar'


def get_some_dataset(ds_id):
    return my_datasets.get(ds_id, None)
```

from datasets.py:

```
import ...

from helpers import Printable

class Dataset(Printable):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.baz = param

my_datasets = {
    'id1': Dataset(foo),
    'id2': Dataset(bar)
}
```

And now Python screaming that

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Printable' from 'helpers'

If I completely remove the Printable dependency, all works well.

If I slightly change the import in datasets.py:

```
import helpers as ma_helpers

class Dataset(ma_helpers.Printable):
   ...
```

Then the error message becomes:

> AttributeError: module 'helpers' has no attribute 'Printable'

How can I use helpers.py's `Printable` from datasets.py, and at the same time use datasets.py's `my_datasets` from helpers.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have editing permissions to both modules, and that helpers.py contains self-contained helper functions, you might want to move the helper code relevant to dataset.py to dataset.py - this might reduce modularization slightly, but it would be the quickest way to resolve the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting circular dependency error is because, you are importing something from `helper.py` in `dataset.py` and vice-versa. The approach is wrong. Considering you are trying to do some OOP and testing them out, let's rewrite the code like below-

```
domain.py
=========

class Printable():
    def __str__(self):
        return 'foobar'

class Dataset(Printable):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.baz = param


test.py
=======

from domain import Dataset

my_datasets = {
    'id1': Dataset(foo),
    'id2': Dataset(bar)
}

def get_some_dataset(ds_id):
    return my_datasets.get(ds_id, None)
```

Now if you try importing `get_some_dataset` from `test` and then try to execute it, it will work.